# How to fix double pocket doors so they stays in the center when closed?

Tags: pocket-door

I have a double pocket door installed that closes together. It is installed by connecting both tracks together. Now each door can freely go from its wall to 2x to the other side.

In hindsight, I should have ordered the [Johnson 1555 CONVERGING
DOOR KIT](http://www.johnsonhardware.com/Content/Images/uploaded/Installation/PD/IN1555CD.pdf).

It is too late now. In my situation, if the 2 doors are closed and locked. I can still shift both doors to the side freely. They just become a 2x sliding door. So the lock is useless.

What is the best alternative to fix the doors/track so they meet in the center and allow me to lock them using pocket door lock?

Comment: It's unclear to me what the problem is. The doors don't meet tightly? They meet but at the wrong location (off center)? They meet but aren't aligned laterally or vertically? Please edit your post to clarify. Photos would be great.

Answer (score 4):

In our high end home the company I worked for built, we never got the converging kit. There was a block of hardwood carefully cut to full the gap in the track, slightly recessed so the cut block allowed the wheels to hit it. It's length was set so each side as it closes stooped just ever so slightly over the centerline of the opening, maybe a 1/16" or 1/32" to insure the doors met well. The block would be about 5-6" long though it could be shorter if warranted. The block was carefully centered and piloted for three screws to secure it in place. Stagger the screws as much as possible in the face of the block to help prevent splitting. Mask off and spray paint the track and block flat black and it all goes away.

Comment: This is the correct answer as it is very easy to retrofit the block that @Jack is talking about. In fact if the track is continuous across the whole opening as the OP seems to imply the block can literally be installed right up into the track. In that case it may be necessary to drill holes through the track to that the screws that mount the block can pass through the track and secure into the framing above the track.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm...the only thing I can think of is a Flush bolt in bottom of one door and an "organizer" on bottom of other door.

Flush bolts come with "closed cap top" mounted in the floor, so when the doors are open it is level across the in-floor receiver...keeps dust, dirt, children's legos, etc. from dropping into the receiver and plugging it up.

The "organizer" (I think that's what it's called) is a "V" shaped accessory that is a 1" wide bar that extends out in front of the other door (you'll need 2 of them, one on each side of the door,) attaches near (about 2-3") from the bottom of the door and "guides" the other door up to (and aligns with) the door that has the flush bolt. When pulled up snug, you can lock the door.

Note: The organizer protrudes beyond the leading edge of the door, so when the door is in the closed position it will protrude beyond the face of the jamb by 1-2". This may be objectionable to some...